# Why do I get space between video and container on movile version of my website?

Tags: css, video, mobile, responsive

I added a video as a background of my website, it works fine but when I move to mobile version i get some space on the top and the bottom of the video, why is this happening ?

```
<header class="v-header container">
    <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap">
      <video src="video.mp4" autoplay="" loop="" muted>
    </video>
    </div>
  </header>

.v-header{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  color:#fff;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.fullscreen-video-wrap video{
  min-height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: set `body,html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}`

Comment: it's already done but It still doesn't work